# VTD-XML reading gives no results

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, vtd-xml

I am trying to read a RSS content using VTD-XML. Below is a sample of RSS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="rss.xsl"?>
   <channel>
      <title>MyRSS</title>
      <atom:link href="http://www.example.com/rss.php" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
      <link>http://www.example.com/rss.php</link>
      <description>MyRSS</description>
      <language>en-us</language>
      <pubDate>Tue, 22 May 2018 13:15:15 +0530</pubDate>
      <item>
         <title>Title 1</title>
         <pubDate>Tue, 22 May 2018 13:14:40 +0530</pubDate>
         <link>http://www.example.com/news.php?nid=47610</link>
         <guid>http://www.example.com/news.php?nid=47610</guid>
         <description>bla bla bla</description>
      </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Anyway as you know, some RSS feeds can contain more styling info etc. However in every RSS, the `<channel>` and `<item>` will be common, at least for the ones I need to use.

I tried VTD XML to read this as quickly as possible. Below is the code.

```
VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (vg.parseHttpUrl(appDataBean.getUrl(), true)) {
            VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
            AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
            ap.selectXPath("/channel/item");
            int result = -1;

            while ((result = ap.evalXPath()) != -1) {
                if (vn.matchElement("item")) {
                    do {
                        //do something with the contnets in the item node
                        Log.d("VTD", vn.toString(vn.getText()));
                    } while (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING));
                }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately this did not print anything. What am I doing wrong here? Also non of the RSS feeds are very big, so I need to read them in couple of miliseconds. This code is on Android.

Comment: why is there a machElement statement in the loop? if result is not -1, the element name is guaranteed to be item...

Comment: @vtd-xml-author: I have no idea on VTD-XML. That is the reason. I will try, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: what is your intended logic? It is hard for me to correct your code w/o knowing what you are trying to do?